# Rewrite URl according to Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

We have an ASP.NET Core Web API running on .NET 5. It has got many controllers and routes that are sometimes protected via the `Authorize` attribute and sometimes they are public.

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase {

   [HttpGet("me")]
   public IActionResult GetMyPublicInformation()
   {
      // code...
   }

   [HttpGet("me")]
   [Authorize]
   public IActionResult GetMyPrivateInformation() 
   {
      // code...
   }
}
```

Well now I would like to publish these REST routes through different HTTP Routes, depending on the Authorization requirement. For example, the route `GetPublicInformation` does not require authorization. That route should be available under `public/user/me`. Whereas the method `GetMyPrivateInformation` does require authorization and should be published under the route `secure/user/me`.

**Of coure, I am aware that I can define the route manually** in the `HttpGet` attribute (i.e. `[HttpGet("public/user/me")`), but - besides that I'm lazy - it would be error prone because we have the information available twice: Once with in the manual route definition (`HttpGet`) and once in the `Authorize` attribute. So if someone forgets to change one of the two attributes, we get an inconsistency.

**Question:** What are my options to automate this URL rewriting (I'm thinking of middleware)? Are there any drawbacks you see using this approach? I have been fighting this idea because I don't like extra magic sauce in my codebase. I prefer explicity, that's why I'm going for the manual route naming right now...

By the way: I have to take this on me because of limitations in Microsoft's MSAL library. I believe I shouldn't have to do this because we host an OpenAPI definition on which routes are and which routes aren't authorized. That should be enough in most cases.

Comment: why not a PublicController and a PrivateController where on the public you can mark the controller as [AllowAnonimous] and the private as [Authorize]?

Comment: You could use System.reflection and loop throw all controller and depending on attribute you add the configration in startup for the controller

Comment: @alessandro I like that idea and would like to look further into it! That would be a good separation of concern. How did I not think about that :).

Comment: @Alen.Toma that could be something I do in a Middleware right?

Comment: In fact you should figure your controller just as route handler then you logic should be manged via command and event, all the best!

Comment: @El Mac yes, its in the startup file. I will still say that I have never done something like this before. So you need a bit of research.

Comment: @alessandro that‘s what it is :)